# Creating symbolic link of xsane to GIMP's plug-in folder does not let use it as plug-in

Tags: symbolic-link, gimp, xsane

As it is stated by the [official xsane documentation](http://www.fifi.org/doc/xsane/html/sane-xsane-gimp-doc.html), I created a symbolic link by the following command (in my case the folders are a bit different):

```
ln -s /usr/bin/xsane /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/
```

The link is there. Executing the above command again results in the following error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/xsane': File exists
```

But I cannot access xsane as a GIMP-plugin, even after logging out and restarting GIMP by doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround/solution of the problem is on Arch Linux (based distros) to remove the symbolic link and then install xsane-gimp from the AUR.